# how to stop gSOAP operations

Tags: c++, windows, linux, gsoap

In my application I use gSOAP in a separate thread. Timeouts for connect, send and recive are set to 10s. When I want to stop the application (or just pause that thread to change some settings) I sometimes have to wait the whole 10 seconds (for example when the IP is set to some nonsense). How to avoid it? How can I tell (from a different thread) the gSOAP proxy to abort the current operation?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the trick is to manipulate the inner socket of gSoap (`soap->socket`). You can have a look here as well, maybe it helps: http://markmail.org/message/dkghy2jtvasr6g5y .

But I really think it depends on your thread model. Maybe another idea is to fire gsoap calls, each in different thread, and manage them from this second thread.

Good luck!